# Mysql replication, master_log_pos sync but tables not update

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

First, my replication config on Master:

```
replicate-do-db         = mydb
binlog-do-db            = mydb
expire_logs_days        = 2
max_binlog_size         = 100M
binlog_format           = MIXED
log-bin                 = /home/mysql/mysqld-bin
server-id               = 1
```

On Slave:

```
replicate-do-db         = mydb
binlog-do-db            = mydb
expire_logs_days        = 2
max_binlog_size         = 100M
binlog_format           = MIXED
log-bin                 = /home/mysql/mysqld-bin
server-id               = 2
relay-log-info-repository=TABLE
```

All tables use InnoDB (XtraDB), the database is used for a Prestashop 1.5.6.2.

Both servers are on Gentoo 2016, Mariadb 10.1.14.
Master use 2 x SSD, slave 2 x HDD.

When I start the slave, it works good, IO and SQL are running, bin cursor increase correctly but some tables are not sync.
There is no error in mysql log.

Comment: unless you have a good reason for it, I'd remove the `replicate-do-db` and `binlog-do-db` entries to see if it helps (especially the `binlog-do-db`)

Comment: another way to test is, login to mysql on the master, execute `use mydb`, then test with `create table mydbtest (id int) engine=innodb`. check on the slave server if the table was created.